# Mongoose/Mongo Pagination

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

Using Express Node.JS along with Mongoose, and I'm trying to add pagination to my get request, however the order in which I'm getting messages is invalid. I get the correct messages with createdAt: -1/createdAt: 'desc', -createdAt, but in reverse order. (Changing to : 1 or 'asc' gives me the oldest messages, and thats not what I need)

```
const fetchMessages = async (req, res, chatId) => {
  try {
    const page = req.query.page || 0;
    const limit = 25;
    const take = req.query.take || limit;
    const filter = { chatId: { $eq: chatId } };

    let query = await Message.find(filter)
      .skip(take * page)
      .limit(200)
      .sort('-createdAt');

    //    query = query.sort({ createdAt: 1 });

    return res.status(200).json({ data: query });
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
    return res.status(500).json({ message: e });
  }
};
```

Solved it..

```
    const fetchMessages = async (req, res, chatId) => {
  try {
    // Required pagination param
    const page = req.query.page || 0;
    // Optional pagination params
    const limit = req.query.limit || 25;
    const take = req.query.take || limit;

    const filter = { chatId: { $eq: chatId } };
    let query = await Message.find(filter)
      .sort('-createdAt')
      .skip(take * page)
      .limit(limit);

    // Making newest messages come first
    query = query.reverse();

    return res.status(200).json({ data: query });
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
    return res.status(500).json({ message: e })
```

Comment: what is the error message ?

Comment: I think you need to use `sort` before `skip` and `limit`

Comment: No error message. I get my messages in this order: 7 8 9 10, and should be 10 9 8 7. How do I reverse order?

Comment: The sorting will be based out of date. Check if you are using some other date field apart from createdAt because - .sort('-createdAt') - is syntactically correct to view them?